# Can the reaction of "Cron Maintenance" in the Rules modules pull data from nodes?

Tags: 7, rules, comments, cron

**Overall Goal:** Have an email sent whenever a node has not been commented on for a certain amount of time (ex: 1 hour).

**Previous Attempt:** Have a node become stickied when a comment is posted.  Then unsticky the node after a certain amount of time.  If a node is not stickied, send an email.  This worked for one evaluation time rather than having evaluation over the life of the node.

**How it could be done for continuous evaluations:**
1. Use the same concept from previous attempt and have nodes stickied when commented on.
2. Have a [Rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) react on Cron Maintenance that will unsticky any nodes that have the newest comment older than a given time amount.
3. Then have another rule that runs on Cron Maintenance to send emails to a user that is specified within a node's field when said node is not sticky.

My main issue about this is that any [Rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) that is reacting on Cron Maintenance isn't letting me pull information from the node table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Previous Attempt: Have a node become stickied when a comment is
>   posted. Then unsticky the node after a certain amount of time. If a
>   node is not stickied, send an email. **This worked for one evaluation
>   time rather than having evaluation over the life of the node.**

Activate the Rules Scheduler module (comes with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules))

Sorry, I missed a step. For your If and Else Statement Add Action of Schedule Component Evaluation and select your component. So you basically re-schedule your component evaluation. Thus, you get continuous evaluation.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow @No Sssweat!  Giving [this](http://i.imgur.com/HQplwTF.png) a try now!

Comment: @KyleRiggen don't forget to add one for your IF statement as well.

Comment: We didn't answer the question in the title but solved the overall goal I guess!  Thank you for your time @No Sssweat

Comment: @NoSssweat I think you should change "continuous" to "repeated" (or something like that). BTW: 15K is coming close ... again ...